MySQL 8.3 unable to find .pid file
I am a complete beginner and I have tried to install the community version of MySQL 8.3 from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/.
I have installed the ZIP Archive version, after which I have done the following steps:
In CMD as Administrator, I have issued the following commands
// Change directory to the MySQL's binary directory
// Suppose that your MySQL is installed in "c:\myWebProject\mysql"
c:
cd \myWebProject\mysql\bin
 
// Initialize the database. Create a root user with random password. Show the messages on console
mysqld --initialize --console
......
...... [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: xxxxxxxx

When starting the server I have used the following commands
-- Change the current directory to MySQL's binary directory
-- Assume that the MySQL installed directory is "c:\myWebProject\mysql"
c:
cd \myWebProject\mysql\bin
 
-- Start the MySQL Database Server
mysqld --console
-- If Windows Defender Firewall popup, choose "allow access".

The above, however, did not cause the server to start, but instead returned the following error message
A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-000001 - Can't create/write to file 'C:\myWebProject\mysql\data\2??.pid' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
[ERROR] [MY-010092] [Server] Can't start server: can't create PID file: No such file or directory

The full console after running mysqld is also attached below:
C:\myWebProject\mysql\bin>mysqld --console
[System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.
[System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\myWebProject\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.3.0) starting as process 13180
[System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
[System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
[Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
[System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
[ERROR] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-000001 - Can't create/write to file 'C:\myWebProject\mysql\data\2??.pid' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
[ERROR] [MY-010092] [Server] Can't start server: can't create PID file: No such file or directory
[ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
[System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\myWebProject\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.3.0)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.

I have tried to locate a 2??.pid file in the C:\myWebProject\mysql\data\ file but could not locate any files of such name.
Really appreciate the help provided!

8.3 is an experimental version. If you are a beginner, then install the latest 8.0.x version.

It seems that the pid_file config directive is not correctly specified in the configuration file, as mysqld trys to create the file 2??.pid which is not a valid file name under windows (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file, reserved characters).
As the archive file of mysql 8.3 does not ship with a default my.ini, you either have created the file by your own or the defaults that mysqld uses when the options file is absent are somehow invalid.
In any case, you can just add the following lines to you my.ini (or create the file  in C:\myWebProject\mysql):
[mysqld]
pid_file = "mysql.pid"

Instead, using the installer should also provide you with a working config file (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/server-configuration-defaults.html )
